# Calculating a product of 3-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, proof-explanation, permutation-cycles

I am trying to calculate the following cycle permutation:

$$(x_d,x_a,x_c)^{-1}(x_c,x_e,x_b)^{-1}(x_d,x_a,x_c)(x_c,x_e,x_b).$$
But I yield the wrong answer; according to the proof (the complete proof is given at the bottom of the post), it should be:
$$(x_a,x_b,x_c)=(x_d,x_a,x_c)^{-1}(x_c,x_e,x_b)^{-1}(x_d,x_a,x_c)(x_c,x_e,x_b).$$
I started by writing $(x_d,x_a,x_c)^{-1}(x_c,x_e,x_b)^{-1}=(x_c,x_a,x_d)(x_b,x_e,x_c)$, then we have -
$$(x_c,x_a,x_d)(x_b,x_e,x_c)(x_d,x_a,x_c)(x_c,x_e,x_b)$$

I start from the right most cycle, and the rightmost element $x_b$ which maps to $x_c$, in the next cycle from right $x_c$ maps to $x_d$, in the next cycle there is no $x_d$, in the next cycle  $x_d$ maps to $x_c$.

Similarly $x_c$ maps to $x_a$, but the middle element of the rightmost cycle $x_e$ maps to $x_e$ not to $x_b$, so my result is $(x_d,x_a,x_c)^{-1}(x_c,x_e,x_b)^{-1}(x_d,x_a,x_c)(x_c,x_e,x_b)=(x_a,x_e,x_c)$.

The source of the problem is the article "[Galois for beginners](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Esmahanta/Teaching/Spring10/Stillwell.pdf)" by John Stillwell, see the complete proof below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand exactly which part of the following routine verification is the problem, but here it is in full: The product of the four $3$-cycles acts on the $x_i$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_a\ \mapsto\ x_a\ \mapsto\ x_c\mapsto\ x_b\ \mapsto\ x_b,\\
x_b\ \mapsto\ x_c\ \mapsto\ x_d\mapsto\ x_d\ \mapsto\ x_c,\\
x_c\ \mapsto\ x_e\ \mapsto\ x_e\mapsto\ x_c\ \mapsto\ x_a,\\
x_d\ \mapsto\ x_d\ \mapsto\ x_a\mapsto\ x_a\ \mapsto\ x_d,\\
x_e\ \mapsto\ x_b\ \mapsto\ x_b\mapsto\ x_e\ \mapsto\ x_e.
\end{eqnarray*}
In cycle notation this is $(x_a\ x_b\ x_c)$.

Comment: Ah thanks I forgot to fix an element which is missing in the cycle.